# Just need a small solution for not rendering a component in react app

Tags: reactjs, rerender, recoiljs, memo

i have used memo to not rerender the `RenderButtons` component but is there any way in react to fully stop rerender and like avoid the extra computational computation for memo and entirely avoid use of `memo` or `useMemo` or it is the very nature if `recoil` library ?

```
import { memo } from 'react';
import { RecoilRoot, atom, useRecoilState, useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';

const countAtom = atom({
  key: 'countState',
  default: 0,
});

function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <div>
        <RenderCount />
        <RenderButtons />
      </div>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}

function RenderCount() {
  const count = useRecoilValue(countAtom);
  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}

const RenderButtons = memo(() => {
  const [count, setCount] = useRecoilState(countAtom);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Add + 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Subtract - 1</button>
    </div>
  );
});

export default App;
```